# How does ee.Reducer.median() differ from just ee.ImageCollection.median() - Issues with a chart?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, chart

I am trying to create a chart that displays an image series from an Image Collection and there are two things that I do not understand:

1. In the first part of the code that you will see below, I do not get what the difference is between `.median()` and using a `reducer: ee.Reducer.median()` while plotting the chart? Does using it twice have a difference?
2. My chart is plotting more than 12 images when there are only 12 images in the imageCollection.

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6f163a02975f01d6f8728feaadf98272

```
     var clipper = function(image){
     return image.clip(WG);
    };


    // Load the MODIS data that is being processed

    var modis = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09GQ').map(clipper);
    var months = ee.List.sequence(1,12);

    // Group by month, and then reduce within groups by mean();
    // the result is an ImageCollection with one image for each
    // month.

    //ee.ImageCollection.fromImages - essentially includes a list of images

    var byMonth = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(
      months.map(function(m) {
        return modis.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(m, m, 'month'))
                    .filterBounds(WG)  
                    .median() // Unable to run this chunk of code without this function
                    .set('month', m);
    }));

    print("Monthly Images Median",byMonth);

    print(ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: byMonth,
    regions: WG,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
    band: 'sur_refl_b01',
    scale: 250,
    xProperty: 'system:index',
    seriesProperty: 'label'
    }));
```

The chart looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you first qeustion: the median reducer is applied on an image collection. That will take the median pixel value at every location the images of the collection have valid pixels. So let's say the valid pixels for band 1 are [1, 3, 5, 5, 2], the pixel will get the median value 3.

For the median reducer in the chart.seriesByRegion(), the chart will plot the median value of all pixels inside the geometry you defined in the argument geometry. That is kind of uncommon for a regional reducer. Most common is a mean reducer for reflectance values or a sum reducer if you want to calculate the total area.

For the second question:

You have to change the names for the seriesProperty and xProperty. The xProperty is for the labels on the x-axis, which should be some kind of time measurement of the images, which you named 'month'. The seriesProperty is the one that labels the different regions in your featurecollection, this could be 'system:index' to get the median value of the two regions separately or you can name is 'Id', which property is similar for both two features, thus it will return only one value in the chart.

```
print(ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
      imageCollection: byMonth,
      regions: WG,
      reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
      band: 'sur_refl_b01',
      scale: 250,
      xProperty: 'month',
      seriesProperty: 'Id'
      }));
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/9dd626eeb6256cb419f4a49111ebb538)

Comment: I have shared the geometry. Could you re-run your code and let me know?

Comment: I have shared the geometry.

Comment: I am also a little confused about defining .median() twice. Is that really necessary? I mentioned it once while creating a median composite and it is mentioned again while creating a chart?

Comment: I updated the answer after you uploaded the feature collection table

Comment: Thanks @Kuik. I am still unclear on why I am defining .median() twice? Could you elaborate on the same?